# Is possible to find the "original" route while executing code from a widget?

Tags: entities, 9

I'm on D9.

I've a node edit form with a *media* field using the *media library* widget.

When a new media is added I'd need to run some custom code to replace one token, of the media path location, depending on the value of the node itself.

However, the route available with `\Drupal::routeMatch()` is `media_library.ui` and there is no *node object* available

I suppose this is correct, as the code is execute during the request "inside the media library widget".

Thus, i'm trying to find if is possibile somehow to get the "main\original" request from in that moment and the relative *node object* or if it is impossible. In the latter case, do you have idea if that objective is somehow possible?

Comment: To make the question helpful to future readers, you should show the code you are using and make clear which hook you are using and which form you are trying to alter. The question seems about a node edit form, but then it says that `\Drupal::routeMatch()` returns `'media_library.ui'`, which isn't the route for a node edit form.

Comment: I guess that what described would be possible when the field widget is using AJAX.

Comment: @apaderno for now I haven't yet a defined code to show, I'm debugging directly inside `token_tokens` because I'm trying to see if this patch is working https://www.drupal.org/project/token/issues/919760 with my use case. As I said, the route is not the one of the node edit form, because the code "runs" during the media insert, which is inside the "media widget modal"

Answer (score 2):

To alter a widget form, Drupal invokes these hooks.

- [`hook_field_widget_complete_form_alter(&$field_widget_complete_form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $context)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_complete_form_alter/9.3.x) to alter the complete widget form
- [`hook_field_widget_single_element_form_alter(array &$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, array $context)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_single_element_form_alter/9.3.x) to alter a single widget element

In both the cases, you can get the node to which the field using the *Media library* widget is attached using with code similar to the following one.

```php
if ($context['widget']->getPluginId() == 'media_library_widget') {
  $field_definition = $context['items']->getFieldDefinition();
  if ($field_definition->getTargetEntityTypeId() == 'node') {
    $node = $context['items']->getEntity();
    // Use $node.
  }
}
```

If you are instead trying to alter the value of a token when it's used for that widget, that isn't possible, since the hook to alter the tokens ([`hook_tokens_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_tokens_alter/9.3.x)) only knows for which entity type the token is requested (`$context['type']`) and for which entity object (`$context['data'][$context['type']]`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code which does a similar job - extracting the node from the entity browser parameters (However I am not sure which media path location are you going to change).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_entity_browser_media_entity_browser_modal_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // @todo Move that code to ClassResolver.
  /** @var \Drupal\entity_browser\Form\EntityBrowserForm $form_object */
  $form_object = $form_state->getFormObject();
  $eb = $form_object->getEntityBrowser();
  $eb_params = $eb->getAdditionalWidgetParameters();
  if (!isset($eb_params["path_parts"][1]) || !isset($eb_params["path_parts"][2])) {
    return;
  }

  if (!is_numeric($eb_params["path_parts"][2])) {
    return;
  }

  $params = [];
  try {
    $params = Url::fromUserInput(implode('/', $eb_params["path_parts"]))->getRouteParameters();
  }
  catch (Exception $exception) {
    Drupal::messenger()->addError($exception->getMessage());
  }

  $node = NULL;
  if (isset($params['node'])) {
    $node = Node::load($params['node']);
  }

  $group = NULL;
  if (isset($params['group'])) {
    $group = Group::load($params['group']);
  }

  if (empty($node) && empty($group)) {
    return;
  }

  $labels = [];
  $group_links = [];
  $group_urls = [];
  $gids = [];
  $gid = NULL;
  $form['#attributes']['data-parent_node'] = NULL;

  switch (!$node ? 'group' : 'node') {
    case 'group':
      $gid = $group->id();
      break;
    case 'node':
      $group_contents = GroupContent::loadByEntity($node);
      foreach ($group_contents as $group_content) {
        $group = $group_content->getGroup();
        $gids[] = $group->id();
        $labels[] = $group->label();
        $group_urls[] = $group->toUrl()->toString();
        $group_links[] = $group->toLink($group->label())->toString();
      }

      $form['#attributes']['data-parent_node'] = $node->id();

      $gid = reset($gids);
      break;
  }

  $form['#attributes']['data-parent_group_names'] = json_encode($labels);
  $form['#attributes']['data-parent_group_urls'] = json_encode($group_urls);
  $form['#attributes']['data-parent_group_links'] = json_encode($group_links);
  $form['#attributes']['data-parent_group_ids'] = json_encode($gids);
  $form['#attributes']['data-parent_group_id'] = $gid;
}
```